# Cannot connect Intellij Ultimate 2016.2 to GIT using PKI

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab, jira, pki, intellij-idea-2016

So, I have been trying on and off to get IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to connect to our GitLab and JIRA server but both require the use of PKI and I cannot figure out how to get this to work. When attempting to use the VCS menu option for Git to pull or interact with Git, I get Git Pull Failed fata: Could not read from remote repository. If I am using the terminal screen within IntelliJ it works just fine after I enter my passphrase for the cert.
Now note that I am on a Windows system.

A colleague next to me has IntelliJ same version running on a Linux system and he is able to use the Git VCS menu features.

Anybody know how to get Windows to work properly with IntelliJ to Git and or JIRA?

Comment: From the link that Dmitriy Smirnov provided: In the "C:\ Program Files\Git\ cmd" folder you will find the file "start-ssh-pageant.cmd"

Before launching it is necessary to create an environment variable:
Name: SSH_AUTH_SOCK
Value: C: \ Users \ username \ .ssh \ .ssh-pageant-username

Comment: Note: replace username with your username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the .ssh/config file in your user home that specified the key to use, by their full path. Then make sure you have Built-in SSH executable selected in Settings - Version control - Git

Workaround - use Native SSH executable and ssh-agent. A similar setup described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000114504-Git-SHH-Private-Key-PAssPhrase)